# Delphi reserved words and identifiers

Tags: delphi, programming-languages

Declaring variables in Delphi brought me to consider a thing that I can't understand.

The question is this: declaring strings, one can observe that `string` is a reserved word, while declaring other data types, say integers, the data type qualifier is not a reserved word but an identifier (i.e. `Integer`, the capital I tells so).

In fact, Delphi lets you go to the definition of `Integer`, which you discover it is contained within the System unit, but it is only representative, because there is a comment stating that some constants (like `True`), identifiers (like `Integer`), functions and procedures are directly built into the compiler.

I can't figure out the reasons behind this choice.

Could someone help?

---

A little explanation of the difference between `string` and `Integer` types. The next code

```
type
  Integer = Char;

var
  I: Integer;

begin
  I:= 'A';
  ShowMessage(I);
end;
```

is correct and works as expected, while the next line

```
type
  string = Integer;
```

gives compile-time error.

Comment: Delphi is *not* case-sensitive.

Comment: Yes, I knew. Though Delphi is not case sensitive, it is considered a good programming practice to capitalize according to the InfixCaps convention. So do I.

Comment: +1, since it is an interesting question, although there may be no 'definite' answer. My personal guess, however, is that the `string` type is surrounded by so much compuler magic that it has been promoted to a 'reserved word' rather than a 'Ctrl+clickable built-in type'...

Comment: What choice? 'string' a reserved word while 'Integer' is not? or, default syntax for reserved words being lower case?

Comment: `string` and `integer` are not really comparable. Remember that the language has extra syntax around `string` whereas `integer` is just a type.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: yes, I'm trying to understand why 'string' is a reserved word and 'Integer' is not.

Comment: Probably historical reasons from Turbo Pascal days that "string" has always been a reserved word while other built-in datatypes are not.

Comment: `string` is a reserved word since the Turbo Pascal times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far i know `string` is a reserved word since the Turbo Pascal times. So the reason to keep it in this way must be for compatibility.

Pascal -> Turbo Pascal - > Object Pascal -> Delphi.

Check these resources.

- [The Pascal Programming Language](http://pascal-central.com/ppl/chapter3.html#Standards) (this shows the original reserved word of Pascal, without string)
- [Turbo_Pascal Version 6.0 Programmers Guide](http://www.textfiles.com/bitsavers/pdf/borland/Turbo_Pascal_Version_6.0_Programmers_Guide.pdf) (this shows how the string is a reserved word)

Comment: Initially, I believe, `string` was classified by Borland as one of the so called ‘structured’ types, along with `array` and `record`, because it had additional syntactic elements to it (square brackets, the max length specifier). It therefore had to become a reserved word, to be parsed in a special way, unlike simple types, which were just identifiers, like `Integer` or `Real`.

Comment: @AndriyM It still has additional syntactic elements

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Yes, when used in ‘the old way’, it is automatically considered a `ShortString`, I know. My point is, initially it was *strictly* a structural type. Now it is more often used as a simple string (pointer) type (syntactically), and it probably has to remain a reserved word because of the support of the older usage.

Comment: @AndriyM: I don't get your point. How is "being **used** as a simple string (pointer)" taking anything away from the fact that the string still is a structural type? Long strings support the square bracket syntax to index into the individual characters just as shortstrings do. Plus: have you ever taken a look at the *str* functions in system.pas and noticed all the stuff in front of the actual string to support Unicode and AnsiStrings with Enociding affinity? If anything the "structural type-ness" of strings has grown, not shrunk.

Comment: @MarjanVenema: You are right, of course, the special syntax to address individual ‘cells’ of strings does remind us that the string is a structure. But that fact alone doesn't really help people who are relatively new to Pascal/Delphi to understand why `string` is a reserved word and `PChar`, which allows for the same syntax to access individual characters, is not. When I said that nowadays `string` is more often used a simple type, I meant that in terms of variable declaration. …

Comment: @MarjanVenema: If a variable is declared as a long string, you do not put brackets after `string`, and so it is not obvious that `string` is a structural datatype. No more obvious than with `PChar`, at least. But when you are declaring a record or an array you can see how the corresponding keywords are special, for they introduce additional specification for the type being declared.

Comment: So to sum up the String keywords long history; In Delphi 1.0, String=shortstring, in 2.0 until 2007, String=Ansistring, and in 2009 and onward String=UnicodeString. In all delphi versions, String is followed by square brackets, are automatically `ShortString` typed. This accomodation being done because a record with a String[100] field was an incredibly popular way of doing binary file persistence in TurboPascal and early delphi era.

Comment: This answer doesn't actually explain _why_ `String` is treated different from other types. Also I don't see what compatibility issues would be created when an existing reserved word is unreserved in a later version. The problematic case would be to introduce a new reserved word.

Answer (score 6):

`string` must be a reserved word, because it is not exclusively used to refer to the type `System.[Ansi|Unicode]String`. If `string` were a simple alias for some internal compiler type, then `string[20]` would no longer work. This is not a problem for `Integer`, because `Integer` always means nothing more than "the type `System.Integer`".

Comment: I doubt that string *must* be a reserved word; I would rather think that it was easier for a turbo pascal compiler designer to implement `string` as a reserved word.

Comment: Well yes. You *could* create a parser that allows any `type[length]` type and issues an error if `type` is anything other than `string`, or if `string` does not resolve to `System.UnicodeString`. But why would you?